# Show that CFG is not a LR(1) Grammar

Tags: formal-languages

Let G b the following CFG (Where S is the start symbol):

```
S→aB|aDc
B→bBc|c
D→bc|c
```

(a) Show that G is ambiguous.
(b) Show that G is not an LR(1) grammar. 
(c) Modify G into an equivalent grammar G′ that is LR(1). Explain why G′ is an LR(1) grammar and why G and G′ are equivalent.

**My current answers:**

(a) I showed that there exists two left derivation trees for string abcc - therefore it is ambiguous.

(b) I simply stated that an LR(1) grammar is not ambiguous by definition, and since (a) shows it is ambigious it follows that G is not an LR(1) grammar.

(c)
G':

```
S→aB 
B→bBc|c
```

I removed the nonterminal D, which makes it unambiguous.

**Questions**:

Is there a more suiting answer for (b)?

How do I explain why G' is an LR(1) grammar in (c)?

Thank you!

Comment: Your G' does not generate `acc`

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to B is perfectly fine.

To show that something is LR(1) you should generate the automaton and show it has no conflicts.

Don't forget you have to show that G and G' generate the same language. Luckily this is simple because your removal of rules only involved a finite sub language thus you can exhaustively show equivalence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Is it through the parse table for the automaton I show that there is no conflicts?